# If you overload operator== do you also need to overload operator!=?

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading

I am using the `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` macro, which creates a class that overloads `operator==`.  I'm wondering if I need to overload `operator!=` as well?

Answer (score 5):

Answer: no!

The reason (that I didn't notice at first) is that BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF uses Boost operators (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/utility/operators.htm), specifically totally_ordered1 and totally_ordered2.  So the less than and equality comparison operators are implemented for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, no. These operators are totally independent, you can overload one but not the another if you don't use it